# Will gunicorn wait for spawned threads to complete before accepting the next request?

Tags: django, multithreading, gunicorn

I have a web server running Django with gunicorn using synchronous workers (my gunicorn config is straight out of the box, no gevent or anything).

In a gunicorn worker process, there is obviously a main thread. I've also written some custom middleware to send request & response data to Keen.io, which I do from a celery worker. BUT, the call to enqueue to the celery worker requires a remote call to my RabbitMQ queueing service, so I do that in ANOTHER thread, so that Django's http response will be sent to client even if the enqueue call hasn't completed by the time the response is rendered.

If you wonder why I do this, let's just say in my experience on highly-scaled systems, you will inevitably see failures or extreme latencies with enqueueing, or really with any over-the-wire call. I don't want these latencies to mess with my response times.

My question is, will gunicorn WAIT for the spawned threads to complete before accepting a subsequent request? Or could those spawned threads potentially "pile up"? This is concerning to me, because I use a database connection pool which would quickly deplete if these threads keep piling up.

Comment: A database is also a remote system in any sensible large-scale deployment. Do you also do all your database calls in threads?

Comment: Certainly true. But there is a strict dependency on the DB calls. I must retrieve data from the DB to respond with anything, but I don't need to successfully make these enqueueing remote calls to respond with anything.